# Inter docker-compose communication over network

Tags: networking, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose file containing one database and many webapps.

I would like to have exclusive docker-compose file only for DB and other docker-compose file for the webapps. This will help me restart docker-compose of webapps, without automatically restarting DB.

Unfortunately even after many different attempts, docker-compose of webapps is not able to 'depends_on' (or connect to) the database running in the network generated by docker-compose of database.

For example

DB and webapp in same docker-compose, which works fine.

docker-compose-adminer-with-db.yml

`version: '2'
services :
  db:
    image: postgres:10-alpine
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: user1
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: changeme
      POSTGRES_DB: tododb
  admin:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - 8080:8080`

What I would like

Docker-compose for db

docker-compose-db.yml 

`version: '2'
services :
  db:
    image: postgres:10-alpine
    ports:

      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: user1
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: changeme
      POSTGRES_DB: tododb`

Docker-compose for webapps

docker-compose-adminer.yml

`version: '2'
services :
  admin:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    networks:
      - composeforani_default`

`$ docker-compose -f  docker-compose-db.yml up -d
Creating network "myapp_default" with the default driver
Creating myapp_db_1 ... done`

$ docker network list
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
4eb66db9e09e        bridge              bridge              local
8290604a966b        host                host                local
1752afa36757        myapp_default       bridge              local
d14d3369531c        none                null                local

$ docker-compose -f  docker-compose-adminer.yml up -d
**ERROR: Service 'admin' depends on service 'db' which is undefined.**

Answer (score 0):

depends_on doesn't guarantee to wait for other service to complete its start process it just starts the app in orders.
To mitigate your issue you can use custom wait in your shell scripts to check if your db is up and running.

Use this code in Dockerfile:

```
ENV DOCKERIZE_VERSION v0.6.0
RUN wget https://github.com/jwilder/dockerize/releases/download/$DOCKERIZE_VERSION/dockerize-linux-amd64-$DOCKERIZE_VERSION.tar.gz \
&& tar -C /usr/local/bin -xzvf dockerize-linux-amd64-$DOCKERIZE_VERSION.tar.gz \
&& rm dockerize-linux-amd64-$DOCKERIZE_VERSION.tar.gz
```

and use this code in your shell script of adminer image to check if db is up and continue:

```
dockerize -wait http://$db_host:$db_port -timeout 300s
```

For more information visit this [link](https://github.com/jwilder/dockerize)

Comment: This is useful info to solve the problem, thanks.

And I assume that we cannot use "depends_on" to depend on a service declared in other docker compose.